# Execute a Program with arguments

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to build a PowerShell script for invoking Python3. Now in shell this would be pretty simple but I cannot seem to get the following converted to PS:

```
../py/python3 myscript.py $@
```

I am lost somewhere in the maze of `Start-Process`, `get-item`, path building, ...
Is there any EASY way of doing that in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is a shell, so for the most part, running programs is what it does well. I'm guessing you're converting a Unix shell script which is where `$@` comes from. The equivalent in PowerShell for that would probably be `$args` or `@args`:

```
../py/python3 myscript.py $args
```

Within a script, `$args` contains the arguments to that script. However, within a script block or function it will contain the arguments to that script block or function, so careful when abstracting things in your script.

Answer (score -2):

invoke-expression -command "../py/python3 myscript.py" $@

Comment: This gives me: `Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument '$@'`

Comment: First of all, that's wrong, as @abergmeier notes. Second, there is no instance of the problem of running a program from PowerShell that you make _better_ by using `iex`. You're only layering other problems on top of it.